# Can't customize UINavigationBar in with Show Detail Segue

Tags: ios, segue, adaptive-ui

In videDidLoad I have code that setup navigation bar in Detail view controller

```
UIImage *emptyImage = [UIImage new];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:emptyImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = emptyImage;    

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

This detail view will show as detail in split view controller and push to navigation stack in smaller device, so I use show detail segue in this case.

In split view controller this detail view controller show navigation bar as transparent with correct tint color, but in iPhone navigation bar not follow my setup and show as default color and style.

Do you know how to make this work. I guess its because internal process that remove navigation controller before push into navigation stack in smaller device.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you manage to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
UINavigationController *lc_navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.splitViewController.viewControllers.firstObject;
lc_navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```